# Как при наведении на пункт меню, изменять картинку в слайдере?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вот такой слайдер:

https://swiperjs.com/demos/280-autoplay.html

Исходный код: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/280-autoplay.html

Вот такой код каталога:

```html
<div id="catalog">
    <div id="title_catalog">Каталог</div>
    <div id="content_catalog">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Школьная мебель">Школьная мебель</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Гостиные">Гостиные</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Детская мебель">Детская мебель</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Мебель для столовых">Мебель для столовых</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Мебель для гостиниц">Мебель для гостиниц</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Мебель для актовых залов">Мебель для актовых залов</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Офисная мебель">Офисная мебель</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Мягкая мебель">Мягкая мебель</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Мебель для кухни">Мебель для кухни</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Мебель для спальни">Мебель для спальни</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Мебель из массива">Мебель из массива</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Стулья, табуреты, банкетки">Стулья, табуреты, банкетки</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Шкафы">Шкафы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Домостроение">Домостроение</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при наведении на пункт в каталоге изменялся слайдер на соответствующую картинку (свойство title и содержимое li совпадает).

Попробовал сделать как подсказали в предыдущем моем вопросе, что бы изменялся класс соответствующего div в слайдере на "имя класса + active"

```js
$('#content_catalog li:first-child, .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide:first-child').addClass('swiper-slide-active');

$('#content_catalog').on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('swiper-slide-active')) { 
    $('#content_catalog li.swiper-slide-active, .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active').removeClass('swiper-slide-active'); 
    $(this).addClass('swiper-slide-active'); 
    $('.swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide').eq($(this).index()).addClass('swiper-slide-active'); 
  }
  return false;
});
```

Класс меняется, но слайдер на это никак не реагирует

Если недостаточно кода предоставил, то всё это установлено на тестовом сайте (http://postav.sidpro.ru/)

Comment: К сожалению код который используется на сайте - не влез в описание вопроса, поэтому пришлось прикрепить исходник и тестовый сайт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте из консоли, такого ли вы эффекта ожидали?

```js
$("#content_catalog ul > li").hover(function() {swiper.slideTo($(this).index())});
```

Comment: Да, спасибо! Супер)